# Code for deleting array data is not working

Tags: java, arrays, function

So i followed code that have be given by my lecture to delete a data in array...but when i display back the data...it seems like the data is not deleted...here are my method for delete function

```
  public static void delete()
  {
  char proceed;
  do{
  int j;
  boolean delete=false;
  int arraylength=date.length;

  System.out.print("Enter the date that you want to delete: ");
  String deleteDate=input.next();

     for(index=0;index<arraylength;index++)
     {
        if(date[index].equals(deleteDate))
        {
           for(j=index;j<arraylength-1;j++)
           date[j]=date[j+1];
           delete=true;
           break;
           }//if
           }//for
        if (delete==false)
        {
           System.out.println("The date search has not been reserved yet");
           }
           System.out.print("Delete another data?(Y/N): ");
           proceed=input.next().charAt(0);
           }while(proceed=='Y');
```

So i edited my code...that delete part was my mistake...but still cannot work...i have to go function by function to get it right...i have 4 function(display,search,update,delete) i have to go through all this function first then i enter delete function...then suddenly it deletes the array...if i let say from display i straight go to delete function...it didnt work...i dont know why

Comment: Can you indent your code sanely please?

Comment: "delete=false" should be "delete==false" or "!delete" .

Comment: ...and stop using `if (delete=false)` which is error-prone (like in your exampe). Start using `if (!delete)` or like Yoda would say `if (false==delete)`.

Comment: For starters, I think you need it to read `if (delete == false)`.

Comment: FYI any decent IDE will show you that mistake immediately, consider using one of them.

Comment: BTW it looks like your loop will not affect/delete last element in your array so each time you shift elements to left you will end up with copy of that element in last two indexes, then last three, four and so on.

Answer (score 4):

If a lecturer wrote this, he's in the wrong job...

```
if (delete=false)
```

Is wrong, that is assigning false to `delete` and not testing (`==`) if they are equal.

```
int j;
```

There's no reason for this to be defined here when it can be done where it's used in the loop `for(int j=index;...)`

```
public static void delete(String[] date,int arraylength,int index)
...
for(index=0;index<arraylength;index++)
```

You are assigning `index` twice before using it, so never using the original value of `index` passed in

```
for(index=0;index<arraylength;index++)
```

`arrayLength` can be gotten from `date.length` so why pass it in when it could be wrong?

```
 for(index=0;index<arraylength;index++)
    if(date[index].equals(deleteDate))
       for(j=index;j<arraylength-1;j++)
```

This means that you are copying all dates back an array step but never removing the one copied from, meaning there will always be copies at the end of the array

```
}while(proceed=='Y');
```

`==` compares object equality and not value equality i.e. it checks if both objects are the same not that both objects (`String`s in this case) have the same value..  In this case it would work but it is wrong, comparing `String` should be done with

`proceed.compareTo('Y')`

or to guard against multiple case,

`proceed.toLowerCase().compareTo('y')`

Comment: So sad, with Javascript this is like a 1 liner with indexOf and copyWithin() :)

Comment: so the part when you say i copying all dates back...so what should i do to actually delete the date that have been entered? i edited it a little bit...and i declared index as global since it use in other method as well

Comment: Yes, moving is copying from one place to another and deleting the original.  Not deleting the original is copying, not moving.
The `index` shouldn't be global, it should be specific to any action being performed.  Either pass its value in OR set it in the loop.

Comment: I understand that...so it seems the code for deleting array is wrong i guess...how to fix it?can you help me?